# How to Add Year & Month to my temporary Transaction Number using stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

I want to have a result like this (USR2019-12-000001) below is my code.
when i add to declare & set year/month i got error 
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
//Original code that got error
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAutoCustom_number]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @max int
    set @max =0;
    declare @trn_name varchar(5)
    set @trn_name='USR';

    declare @trn_year datetime
    set @trn_year=DATEDIFF(YYYY, 0, GETDATE());
    declare @trn_month datetime
    set @trn_month=DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE());

    declare @trn_No varchar(20)
    declare @start int
    set @start=1;
    declare @no varchar(10)
    create table #user(trn_No varchar(20))
    select @max=MAX(Cast(right(UserNumber,6) as int)) + 1 from UsersList

    if (@start<=@max)
    begin
    set @start=@max;
    end
    set @no=Right('000000'+ CAST(@start AS varchar(10)),6)
    select @trn_No=@trn_name+@trn_year+('-')+@trn_month+('-')+@no
    insert into #user values(@trn_No)
    select * from #user

END
```

Comment: I cannot find a part contains date/time variables.

Comment: declare @trn_year datetime
set @trn_year=DATEDIFF(YYYY, 0, GETDATE());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @max int
set @max =0;
declare @trn_name varchar(5)
set @trn_name='USR';

declare @trn_year INT
set @trn_year=YEAR(GETDATE());
declare @trn_month INT
set @trn_month=MONTH(GETDATE());




declare @trn_No varchar(20)
declare @start int
set @start=1;
declare @no varchar(10)
create table #user(trn_No varchar(20))
select @max=MAX(Cast(right(UserNumber,6) as int)) + 1 from UsersList

if (@start<=@max)
begin
set @start=@max;
end
set @no=Right('000000'+ CAST(@start AS varchar(10)),6)
select @trn_No=concat(@trn_name,@trn_year,'-',@trn_month,'-',+@no)
insert into #user values(@trn_No)
select * from #user
```

Updated for your error, it is just a data type issue

Comment: i got this error::  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'USR' to data type int.